# Numpy: how to assign values to individual elements of multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I'm working with 3-dimensional arrays (for the purpose of this example you can imagine they represent the RGB values at X, Y coordinates of the screen).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.floor(10 * np.random.random((2, 2, 3)))
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

What I would like to do, is to **set to an arbitrary value the G channel for those pixels whose G channel is already below 5**. I can manage to isolate the pixel I am interested in using:

```
>>> a[np.where(a[:, :, 1] < 5)]
array([[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  1.,  1.]])
```

but I am struggling to understand how to assign a new value to the G channel only. I tried:

```
>>> a[np.where(a[:, :, 1] < 5)][1] = 9
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

...but it seems not to produce any effect. I also tried:

```
>>> a[np.where(a[:, :, 1] < 5), 1] = 9
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9.]]])
```

...(failing to understand what is happening). Finally I tried:

```
>>> a[np.where(a[:, :, 1] < 5)][:, 1] = 9
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

I suspect I am missing something fundamental on how NumPy works (this is the first time I use the library). I would appreciate some help in how to achieve what I want as well as some explanation on what happened with my previous attempts.

Many thanks in advance for your help and expertise!

**EDIT**: The outcome I would like to get is:

```
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  9.,  1.],     # changed the second number here
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  9.,  1.]]])   # changed the second number here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
...         [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],
...
...        [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
...         [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])

>>> a[:,:,1][a[:,:,1] <; 5 ] = 9
>>> a
array([[[ 7.,  9.,  1.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],

       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 8.,  9.,  1.]]])
```

`a[:,:,1]` gives you G channel, I subsetted it by `a[:,:,1] < 5` using it as index.  then assigned value 9 to that selected elements.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to use `where`, you can directly index an array with the boolean array resulting from your comparison operator.

```
a=array([[[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
          [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],
         [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
          [ 8.,  1.,  1.]]])


>>> a[a[:, :, 1] < 5]
array([[ 7.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  1.,  1.]])

>>> a[a[:, :, 1] < 5]=9

>>> a
array([[[ 9.,  9.,  9.],
        [ 9.,  6.,  9.]],
       [[ 4.,  6.,  8.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9.]]])
```

you do not list the expected output in your question, so I am not sure this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, but the outcome is not what I want. I would like to change only the "G" channel (the second element in the values). I will edit my question clarifying this.